# npx failing to create a react-native project

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface, npx

I am trying to create a react-native project. when I run `npx react-native init project` it fails with the error below. I removed the global react-native-cli but no chance `.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:736
? delta.added.size + revision.prepend

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1055:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (/path/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/metro/src/shared/output/bundle.flow.js:14:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)`

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I am using macOS